# What is this firstObject of my custom UIScrollview?

Tags: ios

I have a custom UIScrollView, and I add 5 imageView as its subviews.However, after I log its subviews array , it has 6 children!! I use storyboard to add the scrollview add drag its IBOutlet. I have no idea where the firstObject come from?

```
- (void)configViews {
NSInteger launchImageCount = 5;
CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);
CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * launchImageCount, screenHeight);
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds =YES;
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
for(int i = 0; i < launchImageCount; i++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"B0%lu.jpg",(long)(i+1)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(screenWidth*i, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
NSLog(@"subviews :%@",self.scrollView.subviews);
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = launchImageCount;
```

}

Log:

```
2015-09-26 17:24:29.626 CustomTableView[60621:7911319] subviews :(
"<UIImageView: 0x7f9680f30760; frame = (234.5 118; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9680f2f6c0>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x7f9680e25a30; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9680e19290>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x7f9680d5ab30; frame = (375 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9680d5a7b0>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x7f9680e26af0; frame = (750 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9680e26280>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x7f9680e2a450; frame = (1125 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9680e2a1b0>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x7f9680e2e1b0; frame = (1500 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9680e2df90>>"
```

)

Comment: maybe the view has been added somewhere else. The alpha value is zero, so it's invisible

Comment: check in storyboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIScrollView has two default UIImageView  to show you your scroll bars.
You probably enabled a horizontal/vertical scroll indicator, and that is the reason you see this extra UIImageView child.